# HP DV5T laptop problems using Adobe in multiple monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, pdf, adobe-reader

I have a dualview arrangement of two monitors that works just fine for 90% of my applications.  However, any time I open Adobe Acrobat Reader to the larger monitor, it fails to permit enlarging of the window to fill the entire screen.  In other words, it seems Adobe crops the PDF view at about the size of the *smaller* of the two monitors, despite Acrobat being present in the larger monitor.  I'm using nVideo graphics on the laptop, and connecting to the larger monitor through the docking port of a docking station. Any ideas how to get the Acrobat to be aware that it has more screen real-estate and use it fully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a kludge, but the answer seems to be, when using Adobe Acrobat Reader to do two steps:

1. Resize your window, and get the icky cropping of the useful displayed PDF;
2. Open the 'bookmarks' (Or is it a table of contents?) display on the left-hand side of your Adobe Acrobat display;
3. close the 'bookmarks'.

That seems to force Adobe to fully use the entire space of the newly resized window.